# Query with multiple schemas - Dbeaver

Tags: sql, database, schema, amazon-redshift, dbeaver

I have 5 schemas under one db. 3 of them have exactly the same tables and fields.
I want to create queries that call those 3 schemas at once.
Im using DBeaver version 7.2.2

I already checked the box 'use global search' and it didn't help.
Maybe I need to do something in the sql editor itself?

for example, I want to call 'users' table and it will give me the data from all 3 tables.

Answer (score 3):

I think to do that you will need to call all three schemas/tables individually. You can still return all results in one go, though.

For example:

```
    SELECT * FROM schema1.users
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM schema2.users
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM schema3.users
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you. there is no way to define this globally? so in every query without union it will call to all three schemas?